# What does it look like for a ball falling to the event horizon observed by distant static observer?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes

Here is the picture used in susskind&Lindesay's book ''An Introduction to Black Holes, Information and String Theory Revolution''

[image]

I understand very well that the ball will be contracted at the radial direction observed by the distant static observer. For example, because we have
$$d\tau^2=g_{rr}dr^2+...,$$
where $g_{rr}=\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}$, we will know
$$dr=d\rho\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{r}}.$$
As $r\rightarrow 2M$, for finite $d\rho$ which is the proper length, we will have $dr\rightarrow 0$. That's what the "contraction at the radial direction" means mentioned above.
 But why the ball will be extended at the angular direction seen by the distant observer? Sure, even the ball is not falling to the event horizon but a normal spherical surface, the angular extension will also be extended, but the drawing are likely to show the angular extension will be extended largely.

Maybe I just take the drawing too seriously?

*I now think it is due to gravitational lensing effect.*

Comment: Doesn't the picture in fact indicate the opposite?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Sorry, I don't know what you mean here. Do you mean the semantic distinction?

Comment: Indeed. I suppose the picture has been misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation

This is due to tidal forces. The equations of geodesic deviation which are valid for objects that are small compared to the (radius) of curvature are the easiest way to qualitatively see that. If you plug in the coefficients for the Schwarzschild metric in the conventional distant observer form you will get the following three equations:

1. $ \frac{d^2\xi^r}{d\tau^2} = + \frac{2\mu c^2}{r^3} \xi^r $
2. $ \frac{d^2\xi^\theta}{d\tau^2} = - \frac{2\mu c^2}{r^3} \xi^\theta $
3. $ \frac{d^2\xi^\phi}{d\tau^2} = - \frac{2\mu c^2}{r^3} \xi^\phi $

Equation 1. describes the equation for the evolution of radial deviations with respect to each other, 2. and 3. the angular components. Note 1. has the **opposite sign** compared to 2. and 3. This results in a stretching of extended objects in the radial direction, while the angular directions get compressed, which is exactly the *opposite phenomenology to what is shown in the picture*. Either you described the context wrong or I'm missing something.

Comment: Here, I believe the drawingg just wants to shown a pure kinematic picture and the tidal forces are neglected in this case because the curvature is nearly vanishing for large black holes. And actually this is exactly what that book discussed.

Comment: @Wein Eld: Aren't the tidal "forces" (they aren't actually forces in the Newtonian sense) purely kinematic? They arise from particles at close positions following different geodesics.

Comment: If you think tidal force purely kinematic, then gravity is of course purely kinematic. Here by ''kinematic'', I mean the drawing should be understood as a coordinate transformation and the ball may be thought small enough to neglect the tidal force.

Comment: @Wein Eld: "the drawing should be understood as a coordinate transformation" - no idea what you mean by that.

"the ball may be thought small enough to neglect tidal forces" - I will stop using the word tidal force now, since it seems to cause confusion. The equations of geodesic deviation above are explicitly for *small deviations* (ie small objects if you consider deformation). They express that different particles fall along different geodesics, which can't be neglected no matter how small the ball.

Comment: @Wein Eld: I just saw your edit... is what you are actually asking how the distant observer sees the ball rather than how the ball actually deforms?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean to ask.